# Powershell script for reporting old folders on multiple shares

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array, foreach, filepath

I am hoping for some guidance.  I need to analyze multiple shares for folders that have not been modified in 6 months.  For each share, I defined specific paths that need to be examined.  A csv should be generated for each share.  The powershell script works fine for checking a single share but I can't get it work correctly for multiple shares.  Here's a sample of the script.

```
$age = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)

# Export path
$outputPath = "D:\Scripting\xPowershell_Results\"

# Export file name
$FilePath1 = "OldMediaPath1.csv"
$FilePath2 = "OldMediaPath2.csv"

# Paths to scan
$CheckPath1 = @(
"\\servername\share1\Projects"
"\\servername\share1\Restored"
 )

 $CheckPath2 = @(
"\\servername\share2\Graphics"
 )


$folders = dir $CheckPath1 | where {$_.PSiscontainer -eq $true} | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt $age)} 
$results = foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $bytecount = (dir $folder.fullname -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum
    switch ($bytecount)
    {
        {$_ -lt 1KB} { $size = "{0:N0} Bytes" -f $_; break }
        {$_ -lt 1MB} { $size = "{0:N2} KB" -f ($_ / 1KB); break }
        {$_ -lt 1GB} { $size = "{0:N2} MB" -f ($_ / 1MB); break }
        {$_ -lt 1TB} { $size = "{0:N2} GB" -f ($_ / 1GB); break } 
        {$_ -lt 1PB} { $size = "{0:N2} TB" -f ($_ / 1TB); break } 
        default { $size = "{0:N2} PB" -f ($_ / 1PB) }
 
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $folder.fullname
        Size = $size
        LastWriteTime = $folder.LastWriteTime 
    }
}
$results | Export-Csv $outputPath$FilePath1 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Looks to me that all you need to do is to wrap your code after the path definitions in another loop like `foreach ($path in $CheckPath1) { $folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $age} ... }`

Comment: @Theo I apologize for my ignorance, but since the number of paths may vary for each share, is it possible to create a nested array?  Or would I have to apply a foreach for every share?

Comment: I'd suggest that the easiest way to improve the efficiency of your solution would be to turn the folder-measuring logic into a [**function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1). ForEach path you want to check, call your new function with the folder path. The function then... 1) Measures the folder, 2) Writes results to CSV, 3) Recurses, calling itself for all subfolders.